# Bootstrap responsive Div disappears on resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm coding a static webpage with bootstrap-responsive CSS and I'm having problems when I resize the window.

I have this section that disappears when I resize the screen:

```
<div class="span9 nav">
                <h1><span class="logo"><em>Academia</em> <b>GEO</b></span></h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#details"><img src="img/icons/mail.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#details"><img src="img/icons/phone.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Academia-GEO/570581836324054" target="_blank"><img src="img/icons/fb.png"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I don't know why the div is not resized propperly as expected.

This is the page:

```
http://209.141.57.95/
```

As you can see when you use a small screenthe blue div at the top of the page disappears and the content is displayed in the white body.

Any idea why is this happening?
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add the built in bootstrap style of 'clearfix' onto your span:

```
<div class="span9 nav clearfix">
```

This will sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

This is a clearfix problem; because all of the elements inside your div are floated, the div collapses down so that it has no height.

This can be fixed easily like this:

```
<div class="span9 nav">
                <h1><span class="logo"><em>Academia</em> <b>GEO</b></span></h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#details"><img src="img/icons/mail.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#details"><img src="img/icons/phone.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Academia-GEO/570581836324054" target="_blank"><img src="img/icons/fb.png"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`<div style="clear: both;"></div>` kinda worked for me, but the real problem was that I shoulda had col-xl instead of col-sm or col-md.  Durp.